# SYS.DBMS_JOB causes error "ORA-01461 can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle PL/SQL on Oracle Database 10g

I use SYS.DBS_JOB to set a job to send an email. [I cannot simply send the email directly because I am sending quite a few emails and sending them too fast overloads the mail server.  Therefore I run a loop to send one email each minute]

```
DBMS_JOB.submit
                    (l_job,
                        'begin HTML_EMAIL (''noreply@mywebsite.com'','''
                     || myrecord.email
                     || ''','''
                     || mytitle
                     || ''','''
                     || ' '
                     || ''','''
                     || mymessage
                     || ''');end;',
                     schedule_date
                    );
```

The text for the job is quite long (2886 characters) and the job fails with the message  "ORA-01461 can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column"

Now I am pretty sure that the reason that the job fails is because the text is too long. However I would have thought that the error message would have been "String can not fit into column"

Assuming I am right that my string is too long, what is the maximum length, and also how can I get round this problem...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL is limited in what you can do directly with LONG fields, and it sounds like your mymessage field is a long. In 10g, you're better off using CLOB fields for something like this, which can be directly manipulated much more easily.

To start with, try wrapping any LONG fields in this call with the TO_LOB() function and see if that works.  Alternately, it may be that your message is overflowing the varchar2 that DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT expects; Oracle may then be treating your string as a LONG. In this case, you'll have to rewrite your HTML_EMAIL function so that it retrieves the message content from a temporary table rather than a parameter.

There's some nice info on working with LONG fields here:

http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=430

Comment: Thank you very much. I am working with your second answer (retrieving message content from a temporary table)

Answer (score 0):

The VARCHAR2 field can accept only 4000 characters max. But this becomes evident when you create the table with a VARCHAR2 field.

I solved it when I figured out that I was trying to enter a 4000+ character string into a Varchar2 field.

I reduced the length of the entry and the error went away.

There were other NUMBER fields in the table, which threw me off the trail initially.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes my job content is formatted PLSQL with a lot of white space.  So I do this before submitting the job to reduce the extra white space and (hopefully) reduce the length under 4000.

```
   FOR i IN 1..9 LOOP
      v_sql := replace(v_sql,'  ',' ');
   END LOOP;
```